# What is the technical term for seeing things from someone else's perspective?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for this fancy word you can use to describe the act of putting yourself into the shoes of another person and trying to see things from their perspective.

Only things I can come up with is 'extrapolation' and it's pretty close, but if I google that word then nothing related comes up. Any help?

Comment: "Empathy" / "empathize" might come close, depending on the context.

Comment: What's wrong with "putting yourself in someone else's shoes" or "seeing things from their perspective"? Do you want a single word? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was commented, context is all-important. The verb to empathize is fitting in most cases. The adjective attuned may work for you as well.